# /media/atlassian-data filesystem is 100% full

Tags: bamboo

When I try to run a build with bamboo I get the following error:

```
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20    write .docker_temp_258181997: no space left on device
simple  03-Nov-2021 01:54:20    Failing task since return code of [/usr/bin/docker save --output=app.tar pl-app-prod:latest] was 1 while expected 0
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20    Error occurred while running Task 'Build Container(6)' of type com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-docker-plugin:task.docker.cli.
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20    com.atlassian.bamboo.task.TaskException: Failed to execute task
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.docker.service.BuildService.execute(BuildService.java:57)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.docker.tasks.cli.DockerCliTask.execute(DockerCliTask.java:70)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at com.atlassian.bamboo.task.TaskExecutorImpl.lambda$executeTasks$3(TaskExecutorImpl.java:319)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at com.atlassian.bamboo.task.TaskExecutorImpl.executeTaskWithPrePostActions(TaskExecutorImpl.java:252)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at com.atlassian.bamboo.task.TaskExecutorImpl.executeTasks(TaskExecutorImpl.java:319)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at com.atlassian.bamboo.task.TaskExecutorImpl.execute(TaskExecutorImpl.java:112)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at com.atlassian.bamboo.build.pipeline.tasks.ExecuteBuildTask.call(ExecuteBuildTask.java:73)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.DefaultBuildAgent.executeBuildPhase(DefaultBuildAgent.java:204)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.DefaultBuildAgent.build(DefaultBuildAgent.java:176)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.BuildAgentControllerImpl.lambda$waitAndPerformBuild$0(BuildAgentControllerImpl.java:131)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at com.atlassian.bamboo.variable.CustomVariableContextImpl.withVariableSubstitutor(CustomVariableContextImpl.java:185)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.BuildAgentControllerImpl.waitAndPerformBuild(BuildAgentControllerImpl.java:125)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.DefaultBuildAgent$1.run(DefaultBuildAgent.java:127)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at com.atlassian.bamboo.utils.BambooRunnables$1.run(BambooRunnables.java:48)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at com.atlassian.bamboo.security.ImpersonationHelper.runWith(ImpersonationHelper.java:26)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at com.atlassian.bamboo.security.ImpersonationHelper.runWithSystemAuthority(ImpersonationHelper.java:17)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at com.atlassian.bamboo.security.ImpersonationHelper$1.run(ImpersonationHelper.java:41)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20    Caused by: com.atlassian.bamboo.docker.DockerException: Error running Docker save command
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.docker.client.DockerCmd.save(DockerCmd.java:126)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.docker.service.BuildService.execute(BuildService.java:50)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        ... 17 more
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20    Caused by: com.atlassian.utils.process.ProcessException: Error executing /usr/bin/docker save --output=app.tar pl-app-prod:latest
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.docker.process.DockerTaskProcessService.execute(DockerTaskProcessService.java:64)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        at com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.docker.client.DockerCmd.save(DockerCmd.java:124)
error   03-Nov-2021 01:54:20        ... 18 more
```

When I run `df` here's what I see:

```
Filesystem      1K-blocks       Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              4079032          0   4079032   0% /dev
tmpfs              817384       8940    808444   2% /run
/dev/xvda1        8065444    5112196   2936864  64% /
tmpfs             4086920          4   4086916   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120          0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             4086920          0   4086920   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvdf      2096128000 2094223308   1904692 100% /media/atlassian-data
tmpfs              817384          0    817384   0% /run/user/15000
tmpfs              817384          0    817384   0% /run/user/1000
```

So `/media/atlassian-data` is 100% full. Cool. What files can I delete to clear up space?

I don't want to go deleting stuff at random because I don't want to break Bamboo. Like I'm cool deleting all but the most recent release for each project but idk where on the file system the releases are. I mean, if I have to delete *all* the releases, that's cool, too, but again, idk where I'd go to do that and I don't want to just go deleting stuff at random because I really don't want to have to rebuild Bamboo and all the build plans and what not from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to configure the Global Expiry to delete builds older than 90 days using the instructions at https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/configuring-global-expiry-289277253.html :

1. Click the [image] icon in the Bamboo header and choose **Overview**.
2. Click **Expiry** (under 'Plans') in the left-hand navigation panel.

From there the rest was pretty intuitive.